# HoldForm/Inactivate and exchange operators

Tags: hold

I would like to know, how to change parts of a formula in `HoldForm`. 
I have the formula 
$$
\underbrace{\prod_{i=1}^N}_{\text{level 4}} \sum_{\sigma_i\in \{-1,1\}}\underbrace{\sum_{\lambda\in \{-1,1\}}}_{\text{level 2}}\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}}_{\text{level 3}}\underbrace{\exp\left( -\lambda \sigma_i x_i^2\right)(x_i^2-\lambda)}_{\text{level 1}}
$$
and I put it in `HoldForm` such that it is not evaluated.
 1. I would like to work with the level 1 content first, change it by e.g. an expansion while the other parts remain fixed. After that I would like to exchange the level 2 and level 3 operators (if you regard summation as an operation as well) and evaluate only the level 2 - level 1 part with keeping the rest fixed. The result should read
$$
\underbrace{\prod_{i=1}^N}_{\text{level 4}} \sum_{\sigma_i\in \{-1,1\}}\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}}_{\text{level 3}}\left(\underbrace{\exp\left(\sigma_i x_i^2\right)(x_i^2+1)}_{\text{level 1}}+\underbrace{\exp\left(-\sigma_i x_i^2\right)(x_i^2-1)}_{\text{level 1}}\right)$$

2. I would like to keep the order and evaluate the level 2 sum while the level 3 operator is not applied but remains in the `HoldForm`. 
The result for the second task should read $$
\underbrace{\prod_{i=1}^N}_{\text{level 4}} \sum_{\sigma_i\in \{-1,1\}}\left(\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}}_{\text{level 3}}\underbrace{\exp\left(\sigma_i x_i^2\right)(x_i^2+1)}_{\text{level 1}}+\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}}_{\text{level 3}}\underbrace{\exp\left(-\sigma_i x_i^2\right)(x_i^2-1)}_{\text{level 1}}\right)$$
To summarize, there are two questions: How do I evaluate arbitrary things(different level combinations or  maybe $N$ or the set of possible $\lambda$'s) and how do I change the operator order within the HoldForm of an overall summation or integration. 
Edit

As recomended I add some code using a slightly simpler example. The code

```
J = Inactivate[Table[Subscript[j, i, j], {i, 0, N}, {j, 0, N}]];

Σ = Inactivate[Table[Subscript[σ, i], {i, 0, N}]]; 

H =
  Inactivate[-Sum[Subscript[j,i,j] Subscript[σ,i] Subscript[σ,j], {i, 0, N}, {j, 0, N}]
    -h*Sum[Subscript[σ, i], {i, 0, N}], Sum]; 

Z =
  Inactivate[Product[Sum[Exp[-β*H], {Subscript[σ, i],-1,1}], {k,0, N}], Sum | Product] 
D[Z, β]
```

yields
$$
\frac{\partial \left(\underset{k=0}{\overset{N}{\prod }}\underset{\sigma _i=-1}{\overset{1}{\sum
   }}\exp \left(-\beta  \left(-h \underset{i=0}{\overset{N}{\sum }}\sigma
   _i-\underset{i=0}{\overset{N}{\sum }}\underset{j=0}{\overset{N}{\sum }}\sigma _i \sigma _j
   j_{i,j}\right)\right)\right)}{\partial \beta }
$$ using Inactivate. How do I pass the $\beta$ derivative past the product and the $\sigma_i$ sum and evaluate it to 
$$
\left(\underset{k=0}{\overset{N}{\prod }}\underset{\sigma _i=-1}{\overset{1}{\sum
   }}\left(h \underset{i=0}{\overset{N}{\sum }}\sigma
   _i+\underset{i=0}{\overset{N}{\sum }}\underset{j=0}{\overset{N}{\sum }}\sigma _i \sigma _j
   j_{i,j}\right)\exp \left(-\beta  \left(-h \underset{i=0}{\overset{N}{\sum }}\sigma
   _i-\underset{i=0}{\overset{N}{\sum }}\underset{j=0}{\overset{N}{\sum }}\sigma _i \sigma _j
   j_{i,j}\right)\right)\right)
$$

Comment: Please, post Mathematica code. Withou concrete code to work with, this is very abstract and mo one wants to retype that.

Comment: I think `Inactive` was developed for just this kind of thing.

Comment: When working with such expressions, I find it useful to replace e.g. `Sum` with `sum`.  This lets you manipulate the expression without it being evaluated.  Obviously, when you have something you want to evaluate you can simply use `expr /. sum -> Sum`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MapAt[Activate[D[#, β]]&, Z, {1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
% // TeXForm
```

> $\small\underset{k=0}{\overset{N}{\prod }}\underset{\sigma_i=-1}{\overset{1}{\sum   }}\left(\sum _{i=0}^N \sum _{j=0}^N \sigma _i \sigma _j j_{i,j}+h \sum _{i=0}^N  \sigma _i\right) \exp \left(-\beta  \left(-\sum _{i=0}^N \sum _{j=0}^N \sigma _i   \sigma _j j_{i,j}-h \sum _{i=0}^N \sigma _i\right)\right)$

Also

```
ReplacePart[Z, {1, 1} -> Activate[Activate[D[Z[[1, 1]], β]]]] (* or *)
Z /. e: Exp[__] :> Activate[D[e, β]] (* or *)
W = Z; W[[1,1]] = Activate[D[W[[1, 1]], β]]; W
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you quickly explain how you solved the problem. How did you get the position {1,1} and how would you do it if if you had to squeeze it in between the product and the sum?

Comment: @Uwe.Schneider, try `Z[[1]]`, `Z[[2]]`, `Z[[1,1]]` etc to see what constitutes which `Part` of `Z`. To differentiate the sum term (which is `Z[[1]]`) use `MapAt[Activate @ D[#, β]&, Z, {1}]`